# How to sort my output form my program without changing the order of my whole loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
words = open(input('Enter the name of the file: ')).read().lower().split()
number_of_words = int(input('Enter how many top words you want to see: '))
uniques = []
stop_words = ["a", "an", "and", "in", "is"]
for word in words:
  check_special = False
  if word.isalnum():
    check_special = True
  if word not in uniques and word not in stop_words and check_special:
    uniques.append(word)

counts = []
for unique in uniques:
  count = 0
  for word in words:
    if word == unique:
      count += 1
  counts.append((count, unique))

counts.sort()
counts.reverse()

counts_dict = {count: [] for count, word in counts}
for count, word in counts:
    counts_dict[count].append(word)
    sorted_count = sorted(counts_dict)

count_num_word = 0
for count in counts_dict:
    if count_num_word >= number_of_words:
        break
    print('The following words appeared %d times each: %s' % (count, ', '.join(counts_dict[count])))
    count_num_word += 1
```

It prints the most common words in a txt file. It outputs this:

```
The following words appeared 8 times each: what, just, apple
```

I want the output after "each:" to be sorted in an alphabetical order without changing the order lines print. How can I do this? Thanks!
Something like this:

```
The following words appeared 8 times each: apple, just, what
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted`:

```
    print('The following words appeared %d times each: %s' % (count, ', '.join(sorted(counts_dict[count]))))
```